# how to code in this session log

Tags: c#, .net

I have coded my own log file, but the tool I am using asks to code this

'Session.SessionLogPath' - below is where I am writing to log file.

I am now sure how to include 'Session.SessionLogPath' in below.

```
 string LogPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string filename = "\\Log.txt";
            string filepath = LogPath + filename;
            if (!File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(filepath);
                writer.Close();
            }
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(Message);
```

Comment: What does "I have tried to include this in various parts of the code but its not accepted." mean? Be more specific.`SessionLogPath` looks like a string that should point to the direction in the disk where the log file is stored.

Comment: I changed the post to show the current log file writing.

Comment: are you using WinSCP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using WinSCP.NET, you can create an instance of the Session Class, and access the property SessionLogPath.

```
  Session session = new Session();
  session.SessionLogPath =  "D:/pathForYourLogFile"
```

Here is a more thorough [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/769049/sFTP-and-NET)